# JavaFX 2.x: Translate mouse click coordinate into XYChart axis value

Tags: javafx-2

In JavaFX 2.x, I am using an XYChart and I want to display the (X,Y) axis coordinate values of the chart as the mouse move across the chart.  I setup an event handler on the chart to handle setOnMouseMoved events.  However, I am not sure how to convert the MouseEvent's getX() value into the chart's coordinate value?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [axis.getValueForDisplay(displayPosition)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/Axis.html#getValueForDisplay%28double%29) to determine the location of the mouse in axis value coordinates:

```
xAxis.getValueForDisplay(mouseEvent.getX()),
yAxis.getValueForDisplay(mouseEvent.getY())
```

Here is a sample which reports the co-ordinates over which the mouse is hovering in a line chart.  The screen capture doesn't capture the mouse cursor - you'll just have to imagine it there ;-)

[image: hoverreporter]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LineChartWithHoverCoords extends Application {

  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");

    final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = createChart();
    Label cursorCoords = createCursorGraphCoordsMonitorLabel(lineChart);

    stage.setScene(
      new Scene(
        layoutScene(
          lineChart, 
          cursorCoords
        )
      )
    );
    stage.show();
  }

  private VBox layoutScene(LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart, Label cursorCoords) {
    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    layout.getChildren().setAll(
      cursorCoords,
      lineChart
    );
    return layout;
  }

  private LineChart<Number, Number> createChart() {
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
    final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart =
        new LineChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);

    lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>(
      "My portfolio", FXCollections.<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>>observableArrayList(
        new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(1, 23),
        new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(2, 14),
        new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(3, 15),
        new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(4, 24),
        new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(5, 34),
        new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(6, 36),
        new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(7, 22),
        new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(8, 45),
        new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(9, 43),
        new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(10, 17),
        new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(11, 29),
        new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(12, 25)
    )
    );

    lineChart.getData().add(series);
    return lineChart;
  }

  private Label createCursorGraphCoordsMonitorLabel(LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart) {
    final Axis<Number> xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();
    final Axis<Number> yAxis = lineChart.getYAxis();

    final Label cursorCoords = new Label();

    final Node chartBackground = lineChart.lookup(".chart-plot-background");
    for (Node n: chartBackground.getParent().getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
      if (n != chartBackground && n != xAxis && n != yAxis) {
        n.setMouseTransparent(true);
      }
    }

    chartBackground.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        cursorCoords.setVisible(true);
      }
    });

    chartBackground.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        cursorCoords.setText(
          String.format(
            "(%.2f, %.2f)",
            xAxis.getValueForDisplay(mouseEvent.getX()),
            yAxis.getValueForDisplay(mouseEvent.getY())
          )
        );
      }
    });

    chartBackground.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        cursorCoords.setVisible(false);
      }
    });

    xAxis.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        cursorCoords.setVisible(true);
      }
    });

    xAxis.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        cursorCoords.setText(
          String.format(
            "x = %.2f",
            xAxis.getValueForDisplay(mouseEvent.getX())
          )
        );
      }
    });

    xAxis.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        cursorCoords.setVisible(false);
      }
    });

    yAxis.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        cursorCoords.setVisible(true);
      }
    });

    yAxis.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        cursorCoords.setText(
          String.format(
            "y = %.2f",
            yAxis.getValueForDisplay(mouseEvent.getY())
          )
        );
      }
    });

    yAxis.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        cursorCoords.setVisible(false);
      }
    });

    return cursorCoords;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: One word of caution about setting event handlers on the chart background region - that region element is NOT a parent of the chart data, but is a sibling. Mouse events that occur over chart data elements (or labels, or paths) will not be delivered (in either the filtering or bubbling steps) to this handler.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to write a comment, but I don't know how to. This is an additional comment so next guy that comes across the problem doesn't spend hours figuring out why.
The answer is correct, but be careful when you use ImageCursor, it gives the wrong coordinates. After deactivating zoom, scroll and dates and all my customization I ended up finding that using a custom cursor will ruin the coordinates of "getValueForDisplay".