# X and Y Coordinates for MouseEvent Not Correct for Java FX LineChart

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, linechart

Added a mouse handler for a JavaFX LineChart, but the coordinates do not match the values on the NumberAxis for the X and Y Axes. Code snippet is below

```
NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
lineChart.setOnMousePressed(mouseHandler);
lineChart.setOnMouseReleased(mouseHandler);
// Add some values to the chart and click the mouse
```

And

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        System.out.println(xAxis.getValueForDisplay(mouseEvent.getX()) + " " + yAxis.getValueForDisplay(mouseEvent.getY()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding `mouseHandler` directly to your `lineChart`, you must add the following line and assign your `mouseHandler` to your `chart-plot-background` of the `lineChart`

```
Node chartBackground = lineChart.lookup(".chart-plot-background");
```

It works perfectly, please go through the following example !

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16476292/1759128

**EDIT**

```
chartBackground.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        cursorCoords.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Mouse Pressed at : " + xAxis.getValueForDisplay(mouseEvent.getX()) + " " + 
                yAxis.getValueForDisplay(mouseEvent.getY()));
      }
    });
```

and

```
chartBackground.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
  @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    cursorCoords.setText(
      String.format(
        "(%.2f, %.2f)",
        xAxis.getValueForDisplay(mouseEvent.getX()),
        yAxis.getValueForDisplay(mouseEvent.getY())
      )
    );
    System.out.println("Mouse Released at : " + xAxis.getValueForDisplay(mouseEvent.getX()) + " " + 
            yAxis.getValueForDisplay(mouseEvent.getY()));
  }
});
```

Comment: I did try this initially but had problems with the mouse listener working correctly. Please have a look at this question.  I was unable to get a response to this problem, so I asked a different question in hopes of getting a better answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937409/java-fx-mouse-exited-seems-to-pause-processing-of-mouse-clicked-and-mouse-releas

Comment: I also note that in your example, you do not handle mouse pressed or mouse released events. My problem is that I am trying to detect the mouse pressed and released events, but for some reason, the approach you suggest seems to intermittently block these events from getting handled.

Comment: Add the Edited code in the code that jewelsea has provided, removing `onMouseEnter()` and `onMouseExited()` with `onMousePressed()` and `onMouseReleased()`. Seems to work perfectly on my end !